# Rails 3: How can I return the player count in my select_all query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I currently have a Game model with a list of Player objects...

```
has_many :players, :dependent => :destroy
```

...and I have the following statement to return the name and id of all Game objects in my DB...

```
self.connection.select_all("select id, name from games")
```

...how can I include the player count for each game, along with the id and name?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
self.connection.select_all("SELECT games.id, games.name, COUNT(players.id) AS player_count FROM games LEFT JOIN players ON games.id=players.game_id GROUP BY games.id")
```